# Specify @column(name=tempname) in application.properties file

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, application.properties, hibernate-xml-mapping

I am using spring-boot and hibernate.I want to externalize entity column names in application.properties file or xml file. something like,

in entity class,

```
@Column(name = @Value("${tablename.prop1value}")) //not possible
private String prop1;
```

in application.properties

```
tablename.prop1value="columnname"
```